# android studio 3.1.1 not reflecting changes in apk

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I have read at least 5 responses to this but none has worked so far... In windows 10, Android studio 3.1.1 (the latestest version, april 2018) I have an app which I have made some changes in but that changes do not deploy in the AVD. The bugs listed that it's supposed to have been corrected for this version persist, and none of the solutions for this problem I have found worked. Could anyone Help me solve this somehow? I have spent days in this... Thanks.

By the way, the app I have to modify is in react-native.

Comment: Do you have "Instant Run" enabled? Disable

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please try cleaning your project and building the app. To achieve this, please click in menu bar **`Build`** and choose **`Clean project`**. Then go to **`Build`** tab again and click **`Rebuild project`**.

Also, please try to restart your AVD.

Optionally, go into settings of your AVD and **uninstall your app manually**. Then click play button and choose your AVD to run your app on this AVD.

If the problem persist please provide more info. Especially please give us more info if you are using gradle build tools, if yes then what info does the gradle console give you, etc.

---

Ok, if you are sure none of above work, please tell me if your changes are reflected on another, possibly new AVD?

Do you have a chance to try your app on real device connected to your computer in debug mode (Developer Tools active, computer trusted and usb debugging allowed)? Do you see changes in your app on device?

Let's give another try to something like this: please open **`build.gradle`** file, then make some slight change in it (like add some space). Android Studio should notice change in gradle file so it will prompt you with yellow bar above with option: **`Sync Now`**. Does your app reflect changes after that?

And lastly, are you sure your changes are not reflected? Can you add something logging to Logcat (i.e. `Log.d("test", "this should print in logcat debug level..");` ).

---

Another edit, have you tried this?

Open **MainApplication.java** in the android/app/src/main/java/{packagename} directory, delete the following code if exist:

import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;

Comment: All the above I have done, no result. Gradle build tools, yes; I have these alerts while build:

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
WARNING: Configuration 'provided' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'compileOnly'.

The config I have done for Android Studio is here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure my changes are not reflected, sadly... Now, something I just noted is that the App.js, in which I incuded a console.log('"Print this please") - not sure about it, did not print anything anyway - is marked as "this file does not belong to the project"... Dunno what exactly does it mean nor how to include this and the other project files to be modified.

Comment: import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;
In MainApplication.java

Was not there

I pasted it there; nothing
I deleted it from there; no changes

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have found the index.android.bundle file, which is, I've found, the one that contains all about my app. This one contains the app programming, as I have found. In this I changed some of the text I was trying to change for testing. In this index.android.bundle I managed to get some change deployed. The thing is that if this is, as I guess, the compiled file of my app, why this does not change as I deploy changes in some other files, and how do I manage this file to include the changes I am making?

Comment: console.log(..) from App.js should print in your npm console. Sorry mate but to help you more I will need to see some code and test it and not guessing. Can you upload your app or possibly a simplyfied version of it to some repo, github or bitbucket?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't as I don't own the code... I'd have to ask permissions to do so. If I get those I sure will, hope you have time for then. Thanks a lot!